# How to disable attachment in infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have a InfoPath form which will get attachment for first time.

During edit it should not show the the attachments, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this attachment control inside a `Section` control & make a formatting rule on the section to be hidden on certain condition so it would hide this attachment control with it. You can't just hide attachment control directly in InfoPath.

Comment: Yes I did the same but when the user reopen the same infopath to edit it should disable the attachment.Is there is any property to find whether its in edit mode or like that

Comment: Nope, there is nothing you can do to disable the attachment.. or the section. You can either hide or show the section, and you can't limit it to certain modes of the form.

Comment: Is it possible to do it programmatic-ally

Comment: I believe everything would be possible programmatically, but I've never tried this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two section having same attachment control. And in one section go to properties of the attachment control and unchecked the checkbox (Allow the user to browse, delete and replace files).
And other leave as it is. And now you can use conditional formatting to show one of them control using your condition. 
This way u can disable the control by actually hiding one of them.